# There is a way in Objective-C to know which app has the focus (i.e the user is currently using) on a Mac?

Tags: objective-c, macos

There is a way in Objective-C to know which app has the focus (i.e. user is currently using) on a Mac?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just updated to mavericks and some PoS keeps stealing the focus every 10 seconds, which is really annoying- does anyone have an app that would tell me who it is? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See NSWorkspace's [-activeApplication](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html).